# Unable to run IE in 32 bit mode or process

Tags: java, internet-explorer

I was upgraded from IE 8 to IE 11. I have java 32 bit version 1.8_75 installed on my machine. When i try to open any website which is embedded with applets, java is not at all recognizing and console is not opening. To test java is enabled or not in browser by navigating below url

**javatester.org**

And i have already unchekced and rechecked 'Enable java content in browser' of java control panel. But not working. Later i found that. The IE 11 process , i was opening is pointing to 64 bit process even though i was opening process in Program Files(86)/Internet Explorer/iexplorer.exe

[Pls click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJfQw.png)

And one more thing i observed that in Task Manager , IE 11 is running with 64 bit mode. Find the image below

[Pls click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMOto.png)

i tried resetting IE settings and reinstalling java. But no use. I have Windows 7 Pro 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

If your Java install includes the 32-bit ActiveX plug-in, you should know that you cannot run 32-bit extensions in 64-bit versions of IE (or vice-versa).

This is documented in an [older KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/896457), which says (in part):

> By design, the 64-bit version of Internet Explorer cannot host 32-bit ActiveX controls. Additionally, the 32-bit version of Internet Explorer cannot host 64-bit ActiveX controls.

You'll need to either install a [64-bit version of Java](http://java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml) or uninstall the 64-bit version of IE and install a [32-bit version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/internet-explorer-11-for-windows-7-details.aspx).

Note that the Java plug-in is a frequently attacked vector for malware and other shenanigans.  Some have uninstalled or disabled the plug-in entirely, save for [very controlled circumstances](http://www.zdnet.com/article/how-big-a-security-risk-is-java-can-you-really-quit-using-it/).  You may wish to consider your use of this and other plug-ins.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance